# How to get value and path from xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xpath, xmldog

I am using XMLDog for reading values from xml file. The problem is that I keep getting null values.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
</persons>
```

And the code I am using:

```
final DefaultNamespaceContext nsContext = new DefaultNamespaceContext();
final XMLDog dog = new XMLDog(nsContext);

final Expression expression = dog.addXPath("/persons/person/name");
final XPathResults result = dog.sniff(new InputSource("/mnt/data-disk/persons.xml"));

final List<NodeItem> list = (List<NodeItem>)result.getResult(expression);
list.forEach(item -> System.out.println("Path: " + item.location + ", value: " + item.value));
```

This is what I am getting:

```
Path: /persons[1]/person[1]/name[1], value: null
Path: /persons[1]/person[2]/name[1], value: null
```

I need help figuring out why I get `null` for value.

In my project I need the exact path and value.
Is there some other way of achieving this?

Comment: Weird that it has name[1].  I wonder if there is another way to specify the name that doesn't imply a list of items / matches?  What happens if you make it /persons/person/@name ?

Comment: if the xPath is `/persons/person/@name` then the result list is empty

Answer (score 1):

XPath was missing: `/text()`. 
I've changed it to this: `/persons/person/name/text()`.
The output is OK now:

```
Path: /persons[1]/person[1]/name[1]/text()[1], value: John Doe
Path: /persons[1]/person[2]/name[1]/text()[1], value: Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> DOM Results
>
> By default XMLDog does not construct dom nodes for results. You can
>   configure for DOM results as follows:

```
import package jlibs.xml.sax.dog.sniff.Event;

Event event = dog.createEvent();
results = new XPathResults(event);
event.setListener(results);
event.setXMLBuilder(new DOMBuilder());
dog.sniff(event, new InputSource("note.xml"));

List<NodeItem> items = (List<NodeItem>)results.getResult(xpath1)
```

Is it possible that you're trying to loop over the DOM without the DOM having been created?

Comment: Tried it, the values are still `null`.